# How to store the output of wget into a variable

Tags: perl, wget

With the backticks, the system call just displays the wget data to the screen.

What I would like to do is have the information from wget "piped" into a string or an array rather than the screen.

Below is a snippet of my code.

```
sub wgetFunct {
    my $page = `wget -O - "$wgetVal"`;

    while ( <INPUT> ) {
        #line by line operations
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `LWP`?

Comment: @squiguy: I'm looking for information if the website was connected to.  wget returns the word "connected" in its info block which I can parse from.

Comment: Believe it or not: LWP does have error handling.

Comment: I'll see what I can find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run any OS command (I am referring Linux Only) and capture the output/error returned by the command as below:

```
open (CMDOUT,"wget some_thing 2>&1 |");
while (my $line = <CMDOUT>)
{
    ### do something with each line of hte command output/eror;
}
```

**EDIT** after reading OP's comment:

Any way to not have the wget information print to stdout?

Below code will download the file without posting anything to screen:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
open (CMDOUT,"wget ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/jpp/6.0.0/en/source/MD5SUM 2>&1 |");
while (my $line = <CMDOUT>)
{
    ;
}
```

Refer [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Using-open%28%29-for-IPC) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

With a pipe-open:

```
open my $input, "-|", "wget -O - $wgetVal 2>/dev/null";
while (<$input>) { 
    print "Line $_";
}
close $input;
```

to check for the connected string:

```
open my $input, "-|", "wget -O - $wgetVal 2>&1";
while (<$input>) { 
    print "Good\n" and last if /Connecting to.*connected/;
}
close $input;
```

Comment: I see it does populate that variable, but is there a way to not have it print to the screen?

Comment: Definitely what the OP asked for, but also a very icky way to solve that problem.

Comment: For some reason, the std output still populates with the wget information.